# How to add content in property dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var fileInput = $("#input-id").fileinput({

        initialPreview: [
            "<img src ='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png' style='width:213px;height:141px;' name='Google'>",
        ],
    });
```

I want to add more `img`'s (that I get from a JSON) to the initialPreview property, but I do not see how to access it. I do not even know how to make a log console of this property.

Comment: plz share ur josn

Comment: Create a new array with all the images and set it afterwards. If I understood you wrong (which I guess I did), it would help, if you could share your JSON and the function getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare initial Data as:

```
var data = {
    initialPreview: [
        "<img src ='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png' style='width:213px;height:141px;' name='Google'>",
    ],
};
```

Now you fileinput will be

```
var fileInput = $("#input-id").fileinput(data);
```

When you get more value eg. new_img_data from JSON then

```
data.initialPreview.push(new_img_data)
```

now reload:

```
$("#input-id").fileinput(data)
```

Comment: Great that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help !